# CSS layout fills missing space

Tags: html, css

I'm having weird CSS issue.
This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JT5HL/) shows it well.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: left;">
    <div class="leftBox">
        <div class="innerWrapper" style="background: gray;">Left</div>          
    </div>
    <div class="rightBox">
         <div class="innerWrapper" style="background: green;">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="text-align:center; background:red; ">Weird</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   width: 640px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.leftBox {
   width: 340px;
   float: left;
}
.rightBox {
   width: 300px;
   float: left;
}
.innerWrapper {
    width: 300px;
 }
```

I don't understand why the lower div consumes the margin between the upper ones.
I expected it to consume only the "row" below the upper two columns.

Tried several different positioning and "voodos" but nothing helped.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the element you want on it's own line, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JT5HL/1/

or CSS:

```
.container {
    clear: both;
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.leftBox {
    width: 340px;
    float: left;
}
.rightBox {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.innerWrapper {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Accepted this answer since the clear keeps the margin (while setting the width to 100% expanded the upper left div).
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either give "**`clear:both`**" property to your "**.container**" class which is the older method.

**SEE Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/KjtJu/1/****

Or use the new solution "**`overflow: hidden;`**" property to your "**.container**" class

**See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8M3L9/1/**

Comment: FYI: [It could be `overflow: auto` as well](http://jsfiddle.net/8M3L9/4/). The key is not leaving it the default of `overflow: visible`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div class="clear"></div>` in your html inside the `container div`
Use `.clear{clear:both;}` in your css.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: left;">
    ...
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JT5HL/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can change your innerWrapper to 100%;

```
.innerWrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/JT5HL/4/

Comment: Thanks but I need to keep the margin between the upper divs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center; background:red; clear:both; ">Weird</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just close the gap in between the left and right by making `width: 320px;`?

**See Fiddle :**http://jsfiddle.net/JT5HL/7/

Or you could add a height to the container like this `height: 20px;` this will get rid of the red in the space.

**See Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/JT5HL/8/

Comment: I need to use margins and padding from the upper divs so I need the row to be "placed" right below the upper ones.
Otherwise, I'll need to calculate the distance from the top of the page and the height of the upper divs.
Thanks!